# Trying to return all objects... stored in another main object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jestjs

I'm currently working with JS, Jest testing, and React!

```
{
      '1': { accountName: 'Dance Party', balance: 200, key: 1 },
      '2': { accountName: 'Whiskey Party', balance: 69, key: 2 },
      '3': { accountName: 'Taco Party', balance: 100, key: 3 }
}
```

I have created 3 Account objects, and they are added to main object called Accounts. I am trying to print out all of the names and their balances using a function called showAll() preferably each displayed on a new line instead of a long giant line that looks bad to read

Tried a for in loop but it will only return the last added object:

```
    showAll() {
        let stuff
        for (let key in this.accounts) {
            stuff = ` ${this.accounts[key].accountName} - ${this.accounts[key].balance} `
        }
        return stuff;
    }
```

returns:

```
" Taco Party - 100 "
```

I tried entries, but I got a giant error and it wouldn't work with what I was doing in React using this function. I DID try values:

```
    showAll() {
        return Object.values(this.accounts)
    }
```

returns:

```
"Dance Party200Whiskey Party69Taco Party100"
```

Lastly, I tried pushing it to an array and just printing the array:

```
    showAll() {
        let stuff = []
        for (let key in this.accounts) {
            stuff.push(this.accounts[key].accountName, this.accounts[key].balance)
        }
        return stuff;
    }
```

returns:

```
"Dance Party200Whiskey Party69Taco Party100"
```

The Object.values and array way got the closest, but I have no idea how I can display them nicely, each account on a new line.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
showAll() {
  let stuff = [];
  for (let key in this.accounts) {
    stuff.push(` ${this.accounts[key].accountName} - ${this.accounts[key].balance}`);
  }
  return stuff.split('\n');
}
```

---

> Tried a for in loop but it will only return the last added object:

This is because of the line,

```
stuff =  ${this.accounts[key].accountName} - ${this.accounts[key].balance}`
```

Here, you are re-assigining `stuff` in each line, so

1. change <strike>`stuff = ...`</strike> to `stuff = stuff + ...` or `stuff += ...` to get all properties
2. Append `\n` to end of each loop to get each account printed in newline

i.e.,

```
stuff +=  ${this.accounts[key].accountName} - ${this.accounts[key].balance} \n`
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works awesome now. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
showAll(){
  let str = '';
  for( let key in this.accounts) {
    const {accountName , balance} = this.accounts[key];
    str+= `Name: ${accountName} Balance:  ${balance} \n`;
   }
   return str;
}
```